# Car idles low when cold but increases when it warms up

Tags: toyota, camry, rpm, temperature

Toyota Camry car 2001; Idle at start up is low when engine is very cold and  gradually becomes "Normal" as engine gets hotter?

I thought it was suppose to have higher RPM's when engine is cold and come down to normal when engine gets warmer.